# How can I apply the style change made within the page to other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

There is an in-site language change script with google translate. I made the menu of this script and there are flags of countries belonging to languages ​​in the menu. These flags change according to the selected languages. I want these flags to be the same on other pages when the page changes.

My menu style changer and cookie script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function setCookie(lang){
    document.cookie = `lang=${lang}; expires=Mon, 1 Jan 2100 00:00:00 GMT`;
  };
  $("#tr").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-lang');
    $("#lang-here").text("Türkçe");
    setCookie("tr");
  });
  $("#en").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-langen');
    $("#lang-here").text("English");
    setCookie("en");
  });
  $("#de").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-langde');
    $("#lang-here").text("Deutsch");
    setCookie("de");
  });
  $("#ja").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-langja');
    $("#lang-here").text("日本");
    setCookie("ja");
  });
  $("#fr").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-langfr');
    $("#lang-here").text("Français");
    setCookie("fr");
  });
  $("#es").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-langes');
    $("#lang-here").text("Español");
    setCookie("es");
  });
  $("#ru").click(function(){
    $("#lang-here").removeClass();
    $("#lang-here").addClass('selected-langru');
    $("#lang-here").text("Pусский");
    setCookie("ru");
  });
})
```

If my use of this script is correct, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to show the style changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in the past and have tried to work it for this question.

First I have a basic javascript cookie controller which is used to read/write the Google Translation cookie:

```js
/**
 * Basic javascript cookie controller.
 *
 * @type {Object}
 */
window.Cookies = {

    /**
     * Get cookie value by key
     *
     * @param {String} key
     * @return {String}
     */
    get: function( key ) {
        return decodeURIComponent( document.cookie.replace( new RegExp( '(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*' + encodeURIComponent( key ).replace( /[\-\.\+\*]/g, '\\$&' ) + '\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$' ), '$1' ) ) || null;
    },

    /**
     * window.Cookies.set( key, value, end, path, domain, secure )
     *
     * @param {String} key Cookie name
     * @param {String} value Cookie value
     * @param {Number|String|Date|NULL} end The max-age in seconds
     * @param {String|NULL} path If not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location
     * @param {String|NULL} domain If not specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location
     * @param {Boolean|NULL} secure Cookie will be transmitted only over secure protocol as https;=
     *
     * @return {Void}
     */
    set: function( key, value, end, path, domain, secure ) {
        if ( !key || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test( key ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        let expires = '';
        if ( end ) {
            switch ( end.constructor ) {
                case Number:
                    expires = end === Infinity ? '; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT' : '; max-age=' + end;
                    break;
                case String:
                    expires = '; expires=' + end;
                    break;
                case Date:
                    expires = '; expires=' + end.toUTCString();
                    break;
            }
        }
        document.cookie = encodeURIComponent( key ) + '=' + encodeURIComponent( value ) + expires + ( domain ? '; domain=' + domain : '' ) + ( path ? '; path=' + path : '' ) + ( secure ? '; secure' : '' );
        return true;
    },

    /**
     * Remove cookie by key
     *
     * @param {String} key
     * @param {String} path
     * @param {String} domain
     * @return {Void}
     */
    remove: function( key, path, domain ) {
        if ( !key || !this.has( key ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        document.cookie = encodeURIComponent( key ) + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT' + ( domain ? '; domain=' + domain : '') + ( path ? '; path=' + path : '');
        return true;
    },


    /**
     * Check if key exists in cookie
     *
     * @param {String} key
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    has: function( key ) {
        return ( new RegExp( '(?:^|;\\s*)' + encodeURIComponent( key ).replace( /[\-\.\+\*]/g, '\\$&' ) + '\\s*\\=' ) ).test( document.cookie );
    },

    /**
     * Return array of cookie keys
     *
     * @return {Array}
     */
    keys: function() {
        let keys = document.cookie.replace( /((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, '' ).split( /\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/ );
        for ( let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
            keys[ i ] = decodeURIComponent( keys[ i ] );
        }
        return keys;
    }
};
```

We then have the code that handles the click events and setting on load:

```js
( function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * The language code that the site uses by default. Tries to grab it from <html lang="{value}"> but will fallback to English.
     * 
     * @var {String} cookieKey
     */
    const sourceLang = $( 'html' ).attr( 'lang' ) || 'en'; // Change as needed

    /**
     * @var {jQuery} $selector
     */
    const $selector = $( '#lang-here' );

    /**
     * A list of the avialable languages {langCode} => {langLabel}.
     * 
     * @var {Object} langs
     */
    const langs = {
        tr: 'Türkçe',
        en: 'English',
        de: 'Deutsch',
        ja: '日本',
        fr: 'Français',
        es: 'Español',
        ru: 'Pусский'
    };

    /**
     * This is the cookie that's used by the Google Translator.
     * 
     * @var {String} cookieKey
     */
    const cookieKey = 'googtrans';

    /**
     * Set the language selector class/text and set the Google Translator cookie.
     * 
     * @param {String} langCode
     * @param {String} langLabel
     */
    function setLang( langCode, langLabel ) {
        $selector.removeClass( function( index, css ) {
            return ( css.match( /(^|\s)selected-lang\S+/g ) || [] ).join( ' ' );
        } ).addClass( `selected-lang${langCode}` );

        $selector.text( langLabel );

        Cookies.set( cookieKey, `/${sourceLang}/${langCode}`, null, '/' );
        Cookies.set( cookieKey, `/${sourceLang}/${langCode}`, null, '/', '.' + window.location.host );
    }

    // Get language on load.
    const current = ( Cookies.get( cookieKey ) || `/${sourceLang}/${sourceLang}` ).replace( /^\/[a-z]{2}\//i, '' );

    // Set lang on load.
    setLang( current, langs[ current ] );

    // Handle click events.
    for ( var key in langs ) {
        $( `#${key}` ).on( 'click' , {
            langCode: key,
            langLabel: langs[ key ]
        }, function( event ) {
            setLang( event.data.langCode, event.data.langLabel )
        } );
    }

} )( jQuery );
```

I've put an example together here: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/f517wxp2/

Comment: I guess this code doesn't work exactly or it changes the texts (language names) when the page is refreshed due to google translate translation. Is there a way to change those language names? And does this code work to replace images? I haven't tried it for this yet.

Comment: Thx for your helps bro. But. Translation is not working correctly. BRUH. It translates the word "cihaz yazılımları" as "firmware" instead of "device softwares".